# What is a DB Link good for?

Tags: oracle, database-design, dblink

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5005.htm#SQLRF01205) is defined what a DBLink is but I really understand for what kind of situations you need it?

What I could imagine is a situation where I have a limited (in size like sql-server express) database and I need a second one to store my data or if I have so much data (like facebook) that I cannot store them in one database. But are there other applications where it is not a 'less-than-ideal'-solution?

Comment: Not exactly to the question but you are not allowed to use dblinks to work around license limitations.

Comment: Just an example, in our company we run about 300 Oracle DB's. Simply you have to link some of them.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of cases.

For example, you can get direct access to the database of a different application. Usually they cannot stay on the same server for security reasons, for incompatibility and so on.

Some DBs are critical, some not, so you put less critical DBs on cheaper standard versions of Oracle but sometimes you need to aggregate data.

Dblink can also query other engines, like SQL Server: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_database_link_sql_server_oracle.htm

Sometimes you split a database to have redundancy or for performance, partitioning your application data in different slots. In this case you can build a view on a master db to query them all.

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason to use database links is to enable database operations to be stored in a local procedure but to operate on the data in a remote database. This can be useful if the data has been brought up to date in a local database, but needs to be recorded for some business reason in some remote database.  A stored procedure in the local database can fulfill the responsibility of making the data available in a remote database, which might be the global database.

Closely related, but different, is the concept of Table links in MS Access.  This gives the Access application a view on data that is actually stored somewhere in a much larger database.  Often, the Access table link is connected to a view in the master database that summarizes or restricts the data in some huge table in the global database.

Either one of these can be used for "pushing" data or "pulling" data.  I have tended to use Access table links for pulling data, so as to mess around with it without screwing up the data in the master DB.

Hope this addresses your real question.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason I've used DB links in the past is for sharing of data between 2 databases, generally for import/export -style purposes. Using Data pump Import with Network Link option via DB link (I believe this option became available in 10g) can save the hassle of dealing with export files and finding the disk space , then transferring the files ... :) (ie leave out the middle man).
With a bit of tweaking, it performs well assuming your network can handle the load.

Additional, as others have pointed out, you could have an actual setup using multiple databases, where they are logically separate databases, however, in 1 of them you need to "look at" some data from the other one .. for whatever reason.

in short, anytime you need to access data from 2 or more databases using the same code/script/process, db links become an option.

Answer (score 1):

A good example would be the (modest) data warehouse I am currently building. I could have everything that it needs to do for the various departments who need to access it to contained within one database.

For security and confidentiality reasons I have created a series of more specific data marts from that feed off datalinks to the main store of information. This allows staff access to only the information I allow, in a more quarantined manor, and allows things like change logs and such to stay outside their application.

Answer (score 0):

In my current job we use it solely in conjunction with materialized views in order to 'replicate' table from one database to another.